# time complexity of a double for loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm trying to ask myself what is the time and space complexity of the following code. This is intended to spit out anagram from a list of words.

```
def ana(input_):
    results = []
    for key, word1 in enumerate(input_):
        a=set([i for i in word1])
        for word2 in input_[key+1:]:
            b=set([i for i in word2])
            if len(set(a)-set(b))==0 and len(set(b)-set(a))==0:
                if word1 not in results:
                    results.append(word1)
                if word2 not in results:
                    results.append(word2)
```

For time complexity, the first for loop indicate there is at least N iteration. I'm confused with the second for loop. It's definitely less than N, but more than log N.
How should this be noted?

In term of space complexity:
this is just O(N) to store the results. Is this correct?

Comment: it's easier to think of time complexity in terms of how does it "scale". the inner loop is still order of N. because iterating through half the item in a list for example (when key is essentially at halfway mark), the total number of items that must be iterated through will still double if the total number of items in the list doubles.

Comment: Note that any kind of "less than N" of the form "N - 1" or "N / 2" is still *of order* N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: A nested loop of the size N - 1 + N - 2 + ... + N - N is still O(N^2).

---

The outer loop iterates through `input_` completely -- for a size N `input_` the loop contributes a factor of O(N). That means the function is *at least* O(N) in total.

The inner loop iterates through `input_[key+1:]`, with `key` ranging from 0 to N - 1. That means in the *first* iteration it has O(N), but for the *last* iteration it has O(1). That means the function is *between* O(N^2) and O(N) in total.

You can quickly estimate the complexity now already. The *first few* inner iterations contribute O(N) + O(N - 1) + ... and so on. Even if we look at the first half of all iterations, the last of these still contributes O(N/2). Since O(N - 1) = O(N) and O(N/2) = O(N) we definitely have N/2 loops of O(N) each. That gives O(N / 2 * N) = O(N^2) complexity.

---

You can also calculate the iterations accurately -- this situation is similar to [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The inner loop performs a total of (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + (N - N + 1) + (N - N) iterations. This can be re-ordered to ((N - 1) + (N - N)) + ((N - 2) + (N - N + 1)) + ... i.e. pairs of lowest/largest remaining.

- Each pair has the value (N - 1 + N - N) or just (N - 1).
- Rearranging our initial N terms into pairs means we have N / 2 pairs.

This means the sum of all pairs is (N - 1) * N / 2.

In other words, the inner loop does a total of (N - 1) * N / 2 iterations. That is O((N - 1) * N / 2) = O(N * N) = O(N^2) complexity.